# how to customize modal width in angular UI bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

so far to cutomize modal width i have done this

```
     var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'AddProtocolElement',
        controller: 'ProtocolElementDialogController',
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });
```

and override its modals lg attribute as

```
    .modal-lg{
    width:1100px !important
    }
```

it is fine but now what I needed is to have multiple customized lg sized modals
on same screen. Here is HTMl

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="AddProtocolElement">
                        <form name="elementForm" id="elementForm" action="#" novalidate class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            <div class="modal-header ">
                                <h3 class="modal-title">{{formHeading}} Protocol Element</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                            <!-- here goes the body -->
                            </div>



                            <div class="modal-footer ">
                                <!-- here goes the footer -->        

                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Comment: There should never be more than one modal on the screen at one time, it breaks basic UI assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust modal with add to your css:

```
.adjustwidth .modal-dialog{
   width: 5000px; 
  }
```

Then add the class to the property windowClass where you instance the modal

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'AddProtocolElement',
    controller: 'ProtocolElementDialogController',
    backdrop: 'static',
    windowClass: 'adjustwidth',
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {
        items: function () {
            return $scope.items;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks alot it is really helpful although I managed it through something else but it is really nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try `width = 150px` in JavaScript. This should work without jQuery.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: Please include an example of how you'll actually do this in JavaScript. Give at least a complete statement and not just a suggestion. The questioner seems to have trouble understanding the syntax (IMO).

Comment: `150px` is supposed to be a string. `150px` without quotes is not a valid number